# Can I achieve this type of pie chart designs with flutter?

Tags: flutter, pie-chart

Am trying to achieve this types of pie chart design with flutter. Am doing it with this flutter package: [fl_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart).
However, I have some challenges.

[image]

[image]

This is my current output:

[image: current output]

1. I can't achieve item spacing here like it is on the expected output.
2. How do I get the bottom side in the center of the items shown?
3. How do I get the indicator line shown in picture two?

If anyone has used this package before, help me out because I can't find a better one to handle my need.

**Code**

```
class _DefaultChartState extends State<DefaultChart> {
  int touchedIndex;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1.2,
        child: PieChart(
          PieChartData(
              pieTouchData: PieTouchData(touchCallback: (pieTouchResponse) {
                setState(() {
                  if (pieTouchResponse.touchInput is FlLongPressEnd ||
                      pieTouchResponse.touchInput is FlPanEnd) {
                    touchedIndex = -1;
                  } else {
                    touchedIndex = pieTouchResponse.touchedSectionIndex;
                  }
                });
              }),
              borderData: FlBorderData(
                show: false,
              ),
              sectionsSpace: 0,
              centerSpaceRadius: 40,
              sections: showingSections()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Update**
Tried setting setting `sectionsSpace: 2` but got compile errors

**Error**

```
D/skia    (13421): Shader compilation error
D/skia    (13421): ------------------------
D/skia    (13421):    1 #version 300 es
D/skia    (13421):    2 
D/skia    (13421):    3 #extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch : require
D/skia    (13421):    4 precision mediump float;
D/skia    (13421):    5 precision mediump sampler2D;
D/skia    (13421):    6 inout mediump vec4 sk_FragColor;
D/skia    (13421):    7 flat in mediump vec4 vcolor_Stage0;
D/skia    (13421):    8 in highp float vcoverage_Stage0;
D/skia    (13421):    9 mediump vec4 blend_src_out(mediump vec4 src, mediump vec4 dst) {
D/skia    (13421):   10     return (1.0 - dst.w) * src;
D/skia    (13421):   11 }
D/skia    (13421):   12 void main() {
D/skia    (13421):   13     mediump vec4 outputColor_Stage0;
D/skia    (13421):   14     mediump vec4 outputCoverage_Stage0;
D/skia    (13421):   15     {
D/skia    (13421):   16         outputColor_Stage0 = vcolor_Stage0;
D/skia    (13421):   17         highp float coverage = vcoverage_Stage0;
D/skia    (13421):   18         outputCoverage_Stage0 = vec4(coverage);
D/skia    (13421):   19     }
D/skia    (13421):   20     {
D/skia    (13421):   21         mediump vec4 _dstColor = sk_FragColor;
D/skia    (13421):   22         sk_FragColor = blend_src_out(outputColor_Stage0, _dstColor);
D/skia    (13421):   23         sk_FragColor = outputCoverage_Stage0 * sk_FragColor + (vec4(1.0) - outputCoverage_Stage0) * _dstColor;
D/skia    (13421):   24     }
D/skia    (13421):   25 }
D/skia    (13421):   26 
D/skia    (13421): Errors:
D/skia    (13421): ERROR: 0:3: 'GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch' : extension is not supported
D/skia    (13421): ERROR: 0:6: 'inout' : syntax error 
D/skia    (13421):
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You set `sectionsSpace: 0` but you want space between your sections. Try 2 (the default) or 1.5. More is more space.
2. As best as I read the docs, fl_chart will tell you what the user is pressing on (see [the docs](https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/blob/master/repo_files/documentations/handle_touches.md)) but doesn't offer that style of indicator. You will have to write it yourself by composing widgets or find another library that does offer it.

Comment: tried setting sectionSpace to 2. does not get applied. instead, I got compile errors

Comment: The error appears to be coming from a custom shader you have elsewhere in your code base. Can you post that code?